Zoom on Touch devices, what exactly does it do?
Frankly, I don't understand what is going on here.

Page zoom in the address bar is still 100%
If I use console.log to print width/height of window, screen or element they still have exactly the same values as they do at 100%, as if nothing is zoomed in at all.
But when I look at it, the screen is clearly zoomed in!
What is going here? How do I even detect this? I just want to implement scroll while dragging an image through a zoomed in (via touch) zone. But there is no way to say it's zoomed in!
Also, calling window/scrollBy with constant dx/dy in this zoomed in (via touch) zone does nothing! It only works when my pointer is on the real boundary of the zone, which is not even accessible when zoomed in (via touch).

UPDATE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VisualViewport
ok there is an actual warning here: "Note: Only the top-level window has a visual viewport that's distinct from the layout viewport. Therefore, it's generally only the VisualViewport object of the top-level window that's useful. For an < iframe >, visual viewport metrics like VisualViewport.width always correspond to layout viewport metrics like document.documentElement.clientWidth."
SO there is no way access the VisualViewport from the embedded (via object tag) element?

This?.

Or more thoroughly explained ..?

Thanks for trying, the explanation itself makes sense (visual viewport vs layout viewport), but the reality must be even more complicated, here are my console.logs:
Zoomed in (via touch)
window innerWH  900 700
screenWH  1707 960
elemWH  undefined undefined
elemstyleWH  792.308px 578.846px
window pageXY offset  0 0
elem offset WH  796 583
Normal
window innerWH  900 700
screenWH  1707 960
elemWH  undefined undefined
elemstyleWH  792.308px 578.846px
window pageXY offset  0 0
elem offset WH  796 583

So everything is exactly the same! Nothing changes!

Just tried "document.documentElement.clientWidth/Height" and it's exactly the same as "window.innerWidth/Height", 900 x 700.

Just tried "window.visualViewport.width/height" - again 900 x 700 regardless if zoomed in (via touch) or not.
update: Ok, this one DOES change on zoom (via touch) if the page is opened directly, but it does NOT change if the page is embedded via  tag, which is unfortunately what I have to deal with!

The key point here is "Zooming ... consists of nothing more than “stretching up” pixels". Stretching doesn't increase the amount of pixels, they're just resized.

You could search solutions for your actual issue too.

A solution to this may be using the Visual Viewport API. This API assists in providing accurate dimensions of the webpage. Due to zooming not effecting layout dimensions, properties like window.innerWidth won't detect any zoom. Additionally, accessing the VisualViewport API from within an iframe/object tag isn't possible so any embedded content you may have won't be able to detect the zoom.
